# PPSSPP becomes blank and doesn't play God of War

Tags: google-play-games

I'm using Galaxy S7 and recently come to know about the PPSSPP emulator that helps to play PSP games. And followed [this guide](https://techshali.com/best-setting-ppsspp/) to set up this emulator.

It worked well, after 4 days, it stopped working. I've already reset the entire settings and uninstall this app, still, it doesn't work.

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: When you say 'it stopped working', how did you determine this? Is there an error message or unexpected behavior that is occurring?

Comment: Means, everything becomes blank/black screen. Then, I need to close this app and open it again.